String literals, List Literals and let statements not working as expected with Mojo 24.4.0
I am new to Mojo and just started learning the language. I am practicing some code on my Jupyter notebook in my Mac mini. My Mojo version is 24.4.0
CASE1:
The below simple code for ListLiterals gives an error for the print statements
var fruits: ListLiteral[StringLiteral,StringLiteral,StringLiteral]=["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(fruits)

var numbers: ListLiteral[Int,Int, Int] = [1, 2, 3]
print(numbers)

Error: Invalid call to 'print': callee with non-empty variadic pack argument expects 0 positional operands, but 1 was specified.

CASE2:
Also let statements in variable declaration don't work ? Have they been removed from mojo ? I get an error use of unknown declaration let for a simple code line like:
let x = 5

Some of the old videos that I am learning mojo from have used let successfully on their notebooks without errors. I am wondering if they are because on a different version of mojo ?
CASE3:
Concatenation of string literals don't work like this on my version of Mojo, but again have been used in the videos that I am learning Mojo from:
#String Literals
#not working this way
var s8: StringLiteral = "Another String Literal"
s4 = "This is a string literal. Less space in memory and more efficient"
s5 = s4 + "and more text"
print(s5) # error given below
s6 = "And more text"
var s7 = s4.__add__(s6) # Even this doesn't work
s9 = s8 + s4 # Even this doesn't work
print(s7)
print(s9)

Error:
Failed to produce standalone archive: failed to lower module to LLVM IR for archive compilation, run LowerToLLVMPipeline failed/Users/ec2-user/actions-runner/_work/modular/modular/open-source/mojo/stdlib/stdlib/builtin/string_literal.mojo:95:45: error: failed to legalize operation 'pop.string.concat' that was explicitly marked illegal
/Users/ec2-user/actions-runner/_work/modular/modular/open-source/mojo/stdlib/stdlib/builtin/string_literal.mojo:95:45: note: see current operation: %101 = "pop.string.concat"(%100, %14) : (!kgen.string, !kgen.string) -> !kgen.string
Expression [25]:5:9: called from
s5 = s4 + "and more text"
        ^

So what am I missing. ? Can someone please explain each of the 3 cases above ?
Please note, mojo kernel is enabled on my system and other mojo use cases are running perfectly fine. These specific 3 use cases have issues.

To run code other than Python in Jupyter Notebook you have to install a kernel for that language, in this case a Mojo kernel.Here is a link for Linux users, don't know if it works with your system.The Mojo language has changed and you could see what changed in this link.

mojo kernel is enabled on my system

@dig_123 the Mojo language has changed recently. these videos are probably outdated. For example let is no longer used. I edited my answer with a link to the Mojo language changes.
